# Is there a way to avoid the need for protected override async void OnStart()

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I realize that OnStart() is just an event so I understand there is no issue with having it return void. However I still get the annoying message giving me a warning

Is there an alternative to allow me to run async methods in OnStart()?

Could I do something like create a Task and have them (or all of my code that's currently in OnStart) run inside that task? or could I use the _ = construct to ignore the output of the Task running inside OnStart?

**Update:**

Based on Nikosi's suggestion here's what I am thinking to do:

App

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public async Task CheckLatestVersion()
    {
        try
        {
            var isLatest = await CrossLatestVersion.Current.IsUsingLatestVersion();

            if (!isLatest)
            {
                var update = await MainPage.DisplayAlert("New Version", $"\nThere is a new version of this app available.\n\nWould you like to update now?\n", "Yes", "No");

                if (update)
                {
                    await CrossLatestVersion.Current.OpenAppInStore();
                }
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var ignore = ex;
        }
    }

    private event EventHandler started = delegate { };

    protected override void OnStart() {
       this.started += onStarted;      //Subscribe to event
       started(this, EventArgs.Empty); //Raise event
    }

    protected async void onStarted(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        try
        {
            if (Connectivity.NetworkAccess == NetworkAccess.Internet)
            {
                if (Settings.Rev == REV.No && (new[] { 15, 30, 50 }).Contains(Settings.Trk2))
                {
                    await ReviewAppAsync(Settings.Trk2);
                }
                if (App.devIsPhysical && (new[] { 10, 20, 30 }).Contains(Settings.Trk2))
                {
                    await CheckLatestVersion();
                }
                // This
                await Helper.PopulateMetrics();
                // Or this
                _ = Helper.PopulateMetrics();
                await Helper.LogStart();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            ;
        }
        this.started -= onStarted; //Unsubscribe (OPTIONAL but advised)
    }
}
```

Helper

```
    public static async Task PopulateMetrics()
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            if (App.CPUSpeed == 0)
            {
                var stopWatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                stopWatch.Start();
                ArrayList al = new ArrayList(); for (int i = 0; i < 5000000; i++) al.Add("hello");
                App.CPUSpeed = 20000 / stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
            }
        });

    }

    public async Task ReviewAppAsync(int count)
    {
        try
        {
            async Task<bool> DelayAndDisplayAlert()
            {
                await Task.Delay(60000);
                return await MainPage.DisplayAlert("Review", $"\nWe noticed that you've used this application {count} times. We'd love to get some feedback for the application.\n\nCan you help us by rating the application or leaving a review?\n", "Yes", "No");
            }

            if (count == 0 || await DelayAndDisplayAlert())
            {
                if (Plugin.StoreReview.CrossStoreReview.IsSupported)
                {
                    if (Xamarin.Forms.Device.RuntimePlatform == "iOS")
                        Plugin.StoreReview.CrossStoreReview.Current.OpenStoreReviewPage("1477984412");
                    else if (Xamarin.Forms.Device.RuntimePlatform == "Android")
                        Plugin.StoreReview.CrossStoreReview.Current.OpenStoreReviewPage("com.ankiplus.Japanese");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Helper.RegisterCrash(ex,
                new Dictionary<string, string> {
                    {"ReviewAppAsync", "Exception" },
                    {"Device Model", DeviceInfo.Model },
                    {"Exception", ex.ToString()}
                });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OnStart` is not actually an event handler. That is a misconception with how the framework was built. You could however create an event and async handler to allow your async code to be awaited as expected.

```
private event EventHandler started = delegate { };

protected override void OnStart() {
    this.started += onStarted;      //Subscribe to event
    started(this, EventArgs.Empty); //Raise event
}

protected async void onStarted(object sender, EventArgs args) {
    try {

        //await custom code here

    } catch {
        //handle errors
    }
    //this.started -= onStarted; //Unsubscribe (OPTIONAL but advised)
}
```

asynchronous event handler are the one exception where `async void` is allowed and can be properly handled.

Using `async void` with the overridden non event handler `OnStart` will cause any exceptions encountered to be swallowed as `async void` on non event handler are *fire and forget*.

Reference [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming)

Comment: @nikosi - Thanks I will use the method you suggest.  Just one question, would there be an issue if the // await custom code here contained a statement such as "await MainPage.DisplayAlert"?

Comment: @Alan2 at that point you would still be on the UI thread, displaying the alert would behave as expected,

Comment: @nikosi - Thank you.  I have a couple of fire and forget methods (if they don't work for some reason it's not a problem).  These are: await Helper.PopulateMetrics();
                    await Helper.LogStart();  Inside my new method, could I run these as tasks or run them with something like _ = Helper.PopulateMetrics(); so as to not be using my UI thread for these?

Comment: @Alan2 By awaiting them (if async) they would be non-blocking so wont affect/block the UI thread

Comment: @nikosi - I updated the question with your suggestion and also what I am planning.  Would appreciate any suggestions you might have.

Comment: @Alan2 not seeing an issue with what is planned. I would suggest awaiting the helpers to run then sequentially. If their invocation are not dependent on each other you could use `Task.WhenAll` to run them simultaneously.